# Web scrapping idealista - Browser/Postman returns 200 and Python requests 302

Tags: python, web

**Requirement**: I want to get the response using Python code (i.e. requests lib) from the following link:
https://www.idealista.com/ajax/listingcontroller/listingmapajaxgrouped.ajax?locationUri=madrid-provincia&typology=1&operation=1&freeText=&zoom=15&northEast=40.89556712488649%2C+-3.520630650041847&southWest=40.879864357074844%2C+-3.5899389309866714

**Situation**: I can access the link without any explicit header thanks to my browser or via Postman.

**Problem**: I can not fetch it using Python lib (I export the code from Postman or make the request code by myself). I receive a 403 code response.

Can somebody help me to interpret how to proceed or what is happening?

```
import requests

url = "https://www.idealista.com/ajax/listingcontroller/listingmapajaxgrouped.ajax?locationUri=madrid-provincia&typology=1&operation=1&freeText=&zoom=15&northEast=40.89556712488649%2C+-3.520630650041847&southWest=40.879864357074844%2C+-3.5899389309866714&uid=k4v5h8vbht9inrlfqrvq3bybmaefj7mhcdfhlpg0dk9&adfilter_pricemin=default&adfilter_price=default&adfilter_area=default&adfilter_areamax=default&adfilter_villalabel=&adfilter_apartment=&adfilter_loft=&adfilter_casabaja=&adfilter_stonehouse=&adfilter_atticstudio=&adfilter_rooms_0=&adfilter_rooms_1=&adfilter_rooms_2=&adfilter_rooms_3=&adfilter_rooms_4_more=&adfilter_baths_1=&adfilter_baths_2=&adfilter_baths_3=&adfilter_newconstruction=&adfilter_goodcondition=&adfilter_toberestored=&adfilter_hasairconditioning=&adfilter_wardrobes=&adfilter_lift=&adfilter_flatlocation=&adfilter_parkingspace=&adfilter_garden=&adfilter_swimmingpool=&adfilter_hasterrace=&adfilter_boxroom=&adfilter_accessibleHousing=&adfilter_luxury=&adfilter_top_floor=&adfilter_intermediate_floor=&adfilter_ground_floor=&adfilter_hasplan=&adfilter_digitalvisit=&adfilter_agencyisabank=&adfilter_published=default&adfilter_onlyflats=&adfilter_penthouse=&adfilter_duplex=&adfilter_homes=&adfilter_independent=&adfilter_semidetached=&adfilter_terraced=&adfilter_countryhouses=&adfilter_chalets=&device=desktop"

payload={}
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.idealista.com',
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'Cookie': 'datadome=tKbHK14umc6tdc0C3DLDjsxJ1kX3q6a-f~ZRocbRhTgXRumg4N2nY7NeSi8Uui3-MKpcjYGQOfLNeZbt74v6NURqVeE-l6~xq-gPQ8tgi8RkR9E0ppAi7gfj~4MCbsc; SESSION=f8a4ee08984fb0bc~3c2ac72b-dbc0-452c-8724-55180ecb93b0; contact50c8f582-b1b7-48fb-b289-4db0b7858527="{\'email\':\'FV8lNdwyz+v09Z/F/DrbGzEeHcwvq5jM\',\'phone\':null,\'phonePrefix\':null,\'friendEmails\':null,\'name\':\'aOcICar3DreKCSZK2v2Irg==\',\'message\':null,\'message2Friends\':null,\'maxNumberContactsAllow\':10,\'defaultMessage\':true}"; cookieSearch-1="/venta-viviendas/soria-provincia/:1672783951971"; userUUID=cf8ec1fa-4373-4322-82ad-4251a0083586'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

**Response** (seems a captcha url, but when I access to the link, I solve the puzzle but nothing happends)

```
{"url":"https://geo.captcha-delivery.com/captcha/?initialCid=AHrlqAAAAAMAcWOy-RJfQlIAWqq_Rw==&cid=4elEJBYQVIIDO9fc6ItAYO-wkIe~bqNWEdc12-vzpidmCuW4n6wji2iyqEbqfKWDe5pKW2Rb1EDFeOGOldTB5FaoyH5UWs7kZ2wUXyBtU9y8wNUBwT61nEG5TJv6KsLi&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.idealista.com%2Fajax%2Flistingcontroller%2Flistingmapajaxgrouped.ajax%3FlocationUri%3Del-berrueco-madrid%26typology%3D1%26operation%3D1%26freeText%3D%26zoom%3D12%26northEast%3D40.94090616280333%252C%2B-3.280011876220712%26southWest%3D40.815265802881775%252C%2B-3.8344781237793057%26uid%3Dklgivra5u3jhq5jdz9ld5lvrxt3lx8eithlbeeiaaoe%26adfilter_pricemin%3Ddefault%26adfilter_price%3Ddefault%26adfilter_area%3Ddefault%26adfilter_areamax%3Ddefault%26adfilter_rooms_0%3D%26adfilter_rooms_1%3D%26adfilter_rooms_2%3D%26adfilter_rooms_3%3D%26adfilter_rooms_4_more%3D%26adfilter_baths_1%3D%26adfilter_baths_2%3D%26adfilter_baths_3%3D%26adfilter_newconstruction%3D%26adfilter_goodcondition%3D%26adfilter_toberestored%3D%26adfilter_hasairconditioning%3D%26adfilter_wardrobes%3D%26adfilter_lift%3D%26adfilter_flatlocation%3D%26adfilter_parkingspace%3D%26adfilter_garden%3D%26adfilter_swimmingpool%3D%26adfilter_hasterrace%3D%26adfilter_boxroom%3D%26adfilter_accessibleHousing%3D%26adfilter_top_floor%3D%26adfilter_intermediate_floor%3D%26adfilter_ground_floor%3D%26adfilter_hasplan%3D%26adfilter_digitalvisit%3D%26adfilter_agencyisabank%3D%26adfilter_published%3Ddefault%26adfilter_onlyflats%3D%26adfilter_penthouse%3D%26adfilter_duplex%3D%26adfilter_homes%3D%26adfilter_independent%3D%26adfilter_semidetached%3D%26adfilter_terraced%3D%26adfilter_countryhouses%3D%26adfilter_chalets%3D%26device%3Ddesktop&hash=AC81AADC3279CA4C7B968B717FBB30&t=fe&s=17156&e=90b9e874340696f9408158a50d47a2ef9d1a69a48366f440da9f0f5be2f52aa9"}
```

Please, avoid solutions like Selenium (it must not be based on an executable, like a browser)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked up the meaning of a 302 http status code? It indicates the client was redirected.

This typically shows up when the request was redirected and your browser and Postman are configured to follow redirections, but your Python code is not.

Another option (and that appears to be the case here) is that the server detects that an automated system may be trying to access the service and redirects the request to a captcha which will need to be resolved before redirecting again to the actual target.

You'd need to either convince the server you're not an automated system by coming up with a better header on the request, or solve the captcha.

In either case, you need to be aware that you're trying to do something that the owner of the website doesn't want you to do. Depending on where you and the site are at, and what you're planning to do with the data, that may be legal, but don't expect the owner of the site to play nice and not break your script by changing how the website works. If you want something more stable and above board, you should look for an API.

Edit: you indicate you now receive a 403,
You asked some additional questions in the comments:

1. "*It is not returning a 302 code, it is a 403-forbidden (you can check in the browser you are not redirected).*" 
   The same logic applies. A 403 indicates your request is not authorised, and you need some sort of authentication in the request (likely a session cookie or something of the sort). Your browser will obtain that from a previous request and automatically send it along, your Python code does not, you'll need to do that yourself.
2. "*This is legal 100%, just trying to access info programmatically.*" 
   Saying that doesn't make it true. In fact [on the website it says](https://www.idealista.com/ayuda/articulos/legal-statement/?lang=en): "What you can and cannot do on idealista: You can surf the Website and Apps, sign up to be able to save your searches and favourite properties, contact advertisers, publish properties to sell or rent, and hire other additional services from us. **You may not** damage third parties or idealista, break the law, **use automatic mechanisms to copy or extract our content**, create false contacts nor use the user access details of other people without their permission. If you are an advertiser, we recommend that you read our rules for publishing listings in detail." (my emphasis) So, you have no rights to the content obtained the way you did, it was not freely given and in fact contravenes the 'General Conditions' legal statement. It may be technically legal to scrape the site, that doesn't automatically mean you're allowed to do anything with the data you obtain.

   2.1 "*How can the system detect the request is caming from an automated system?? What is the difference with a Postman/browser? maybe TLS handshake?*" 
   As indicated above, something may be missing from a cookie, the User-Agent request header may have an unacceptable value, more complex detection methods are available as well.

   2.2 "*To solve the captcha I would need to interact with it via python IDE?*" 
   That would seem to defeat the purpose of scraping. The whole point of a captcha is to ensure a human is at the helm (also a clear indication that the owner does *not* want you to scrape it). You can avoid the captcha if the site has no reason to believe anything other than a human is using it, which is why people often use solutions like Selenium to drive their scraping, since that is about as close as you can get to 'normal' access.

Comment: Hi Grismar, thank you for the answer. 1) It is not returning a 302 scode, it is a 403-forbidden (you can check in the browser you are not redirected). 2) This is legal 100%, just trying to access info programmatically. 2.1.) How can the system detect the request is caming from an automated system?? What is the difference with a Postman/browser? maybe TLS handshake?2.2) To solve the captcha I would need to interact with it via python IDE? Because when I try to open the URL from my browser it is not working

Comment: I've provided some more information and answers to your additional questions in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you put in the comments: 1. What I am not understanding is why I can not access via Python code but yes on the browser - If you realize when access the url, you are not adding any custom header/cookie... (try to do it on incognite mode); in other situations, the app inject a cookie or some custom header to verify the query (this is not the case) 2. N/A as I mentioned befored. 2.2. I can solve it with selenium, but not with python code (this point is not relevant - not need further clariffication)

Comment: As indicated, it's not just cookies, it's also header information that a browser *always* sends along, even from incognito mode, like the User-Agent header field. There may also be more technical ways to tell, like how the client reacts to certain status codes in the http headers. Have a look at Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) in your browser and look at the headers on the network request for the actual page.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to say. When you make the request and you inspect it; it only has a few headers (nothing weird); even when I export it to Postman and open the console to get all the headers that are sent to the server; these are not weird (basic ones like header user-agent...)

Comment: If you have a very specific example, of setting all header fields the same as you think they are being submitted from Postman, I recommend starting a new question, specifying those details and asking why there's still a different outcome. I can keep guessing, but this is not what the comments are for. I think I answered your original question - if you disagree, you should update the question and include those same details.

Comment: 1. If you have a very specific example, of setting all header fields the same as you think they are being submitted from Postman, I recommend starting a new question, specifying those details and asking why there's still a different outcome.: The very specific example is in the question from the beginning //  2. I can keep guessing, but this is not what the comments are for. I think I answered your original question - if you disagree, you should update the question and include those same details - pls, see the title: Browser/Postman returns 200 and Python requests 302

Comment: Yes, and as I explained in the answer, that's Python not following the redirect. But you then insisted that was not the status code you were getting (without updating the question). All the information is here.